# Boto3 : Download file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Trying to download an older version of a file using boto3. I currently have this to download the latest version and this works.

```
get_obj = s3.download_file(
        Bucket="my_bucket",
        Key="testfile.txt",
        Filename='myfile'
        )
```

However I want to grab a previous version of the file and going thru the docs I see that `download_object` does [allow extra args](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) . [More docs here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer.ALLOWED_DOWNLOAD_ARGS)

So I changed my code to this:

```
data = {'VersionId': prev_ver_id}

get_obj = s3.download_file(
        Bucket="my_bucket",
        Key="testfile.txt",
        Filename='myfile',
        **data)
```

However this keeps throwing `TypeError: download_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'VersionId'`

Im not sure what Im missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the extra args in a dict:

```
response = s3.download_file(
    Bucket="my_bucket",
    Key="testfile.txt",
    Filename='myfile',
    ExtraArgs={'VersionId': prev_ver_id},
)
```